# Can I create List of comboBox type?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, comboboxlist

Good day everybody

Can I create List of JCombobox type .. and fill it with comboBoxes like this or something ?

```
List<JCombobox> comboBoxList = new arrayList<JComboBox>();
comboBoxList.add(JComboBox);
```

or something like above???

Comment: it should be `ArrayList`.you can also use diamond operator `List<JComboBox> comboBoxList = new ArrayList<>();`
but didn't you try it ?

Comment: can i do like this comboboxList.add(comboBox);

Comment: yes.since it is a arraylist,you can add jcombobox to it.same as you adding elements to arraylist.

Comment: Yes you can have that kind of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have an `ArrayList` which can contain `JComboBox` type elements

You can create ArrayList like this:

```
  List<JComboBox> comboBoxList = new ArrayList<>(); // you can also provide capacity here
```

And then you can create JComboBox instances by using any of the [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox(javax.swing.ComboBoxModel))

```
  JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox();
  // set properties of JComboBox here
```

And then you can add this to your `comboBoxList` by

```
  comboBoxList.add(combo1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this way get me compile error ... check this 
http://www.mrkzgulf.com/uploads/1462445181351.jpg

Comment: Unable to open that link please put compiler error in comment

Comment: type what you suggested me exactly .. this message comes out : 
type List does not take paramaters
@sanjeev

Comment: the error takes place at this line :
List<JComboBox> comboBoxList = new ArrayList<>();
try this : 
http://s32.postimg.org/9a4nvpkcl/combobox_List.jpg

Comment: I think you are using `java.awt.List`, you need to use `java.util.List`

Comment: i fix the import .. it is working now .. thank you too much friend